# How do I define an anonymous generic interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am looking to find a way to make the following piece of code compile without having to declare an interface.

```
var a : <A>{ (value: A): void; (): A; } = null;
```

Comment: Why can't you create a named interface? Is the operation so abstract you can't even name it?

Comment: I don't want to pollute the namespace with single-time-used interfaces.

Comment: I haven't used TS in a while, but can't you do something like a local, "detail" namespace?

Comment: Of course I can come up with a workaround, but the question is about finding a way to avoid doing that.

Comment: I'd say you're trying to *work around* the most natural solution (at least in the C++ world, and certainly not only there) here.

Comment: TypeScript claims to support anonymous types, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a generic type like that to even exist. It's the same reason you can't write `Foo<T> x;` in C++ without an actual `T` in scope -- once the type is manifest, it has to be bound.

You can write this instead, which probably has the semantics you wanted anyway.

```
var a: { <A>(value: A): void; <A>(): A; } = null;
```

If that's not what you were looking for, it'd be useful to post some examples of what valid and invalid calls on `a` would look like.

Comment: It turned out that my case was `{ <A>(value: A): void; <B>(): B; }`